# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<String>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<turon.Model.Products_Products>

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

```
public IEnumerable<Products_Products> getprod()
{
    var db = new Model.atengturonDBEntities();
    IEnumerable<Products_Products> x = new List<Products_Products>();
    var test = (from name in db.Products_Products select 
                    name.ProductName).ToList();
    x = test;
    return x;
}
```

why am I getting this error? I also tried to change all 'IEnumerable' to 'List', Help me! thanks :)

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exist(are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error message is quite clear. Your LINQ query returns collection of `string`, because you're selecting `name.ProductName`, but your method is declared to return collection of `Products_Products`.

Change your LINQ query to return not just `ProductName` but the product itself:

```
IEnumerable<Products_Products> x = new List<Products_Products>();
var test = (from name in db.Products_Products select 
                name).ToList();
```

(can also be replaced with just `db.Products_Products.ToList()`.

Or change your method to return `IEnumerable<string>`

```
public IEnumerable<string> getprod()
```

Answer (score 3):

The Lambada expression is getting the ProductName from each product and collect it as a collection of strings.. I suggest you to change it to:

```
return (from name in db.Products_Products select 
             name).ToList();
```

Comment: I love the term "Lambada expression" ;-).

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.FirstOrDefault` or `First`  it always solves my proplems